# Process HTTP MIME REST message in java

Tags: java, rest, http, mime, mime-message

I am debugging an application which gets a bad Request, Response from JAX-RS. I have monitored the HTTP message using TCPMon and figured out that The MIME boundary in Header does not match the Boundary in message parts.

What I am trying to do is, Writing a simple java program that changes that boundary of the message part according to the header MIME boundary.

but When I edit the String and sent it back to the JAX-RS service I get errors like Unexpected EndOfLine,Uxexpected EOF.

What I did was , opened a server socket and read the message from incoming connection from my application and edited the MIME boundary of Message parts

```
String mimeBoundary = message.toString().split("\r\n")[5].split(";")[1].split("=")[1];
message.replace(message.indexOf("MIMEBoundary"), message.indexOf("MIMEBoundary")+61,mimeBoundary);
message.replace(message.indexOf("MIMEBoundary"),message.indexOf("MIMEBoundary")+61,mimeBoundary);
```

And send the Message(String) to the JAX-RS service.

What am I doing wrong here? someone please help.
Thank You.